# Run test inside container with Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run some test with Gitlab CI. I was building the Docker image and running it with the script but I just saw that I can launch the test directly in the Docker image with the image argument. But I check the cgroup it appear that my script are not running in the docker.

```
test_end_to_end:
  stage: test
  image: my-image

  tags:
    - end-to-end-ci

  script:
    - cat /proc/1/cgroup
```

Comment: What do pipeline logs say at the beginning? When I run pipeline on docker runner logs start with something like `Using Docker executor with image <image name>`